# Setup reversed proxy on heroku to heroku app

Tags: nginx, heroku, proxy, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I have a backend server running nodejs on heroku for example **app1.herokuapp.com**
I have a balancer server running nginx on heroku for example **balancer.herokuapp.com** with such nginx config

```
upstream heroku {
    server app1.herokuapp.com;
    # server app2.herokuapp.com;
    # etc..
}

server {
    listen <%= ENV['PORT']%>;
    server_name _;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://heroku;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

the problem is, when after deploying balancer app i'm trying to access my backed through proxy i'm getting such error from heroku

> No such app (There's nothing here, yet.)

When i'm running backend server and balancer on localhost everything seems fine

Comment: Any solution on this?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you k=just have to add the section below explicitly specifying the application domain

```
proxy_set_header Host my-other-app.herokuapp.com
```

Kindly follow the details [here](https://github.com/ryandotsmith/nginx-buildpack/issues/59)

Answer (score 0):

Heroku Round-Robin Load Balancing

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        set_formatted_local_time $upstream "%S";
        if ($upstream ~ 00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12|13|14|15) {
            set $backend_url http://phpmyadmin-heroku.herokuapp.com;
            set $backend_host phpmyadmin-heroku.herokuapp.com;
        }
        if ($upstream ~ 16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30) {
            set $backend_url https://helloenvoy.herokuapp.com;
            set $backend_host helloenvoy.herokuapp.com;
        }
        if ($upstream ~ 31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|43|44|45) {
            set $backend_url http://powr.herokuapp.com;
            set $backend_host powr.herokuapp.com;
        }
        if ($upstream ~ 46|47|48|49|50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59) {
            set $backend_url https://blog.heroku.com;
            set $backend_host blog.heroku.com;
        }
        proxy_pass $backend_url;
        proxy_set_header Host $backend_host;
    }
    location /this_is_ip_resolver_just_ignore_it_1 {
        proxy_pass http://phpmyadmin-heroku.herokuapp.com;
    }
    location /this_is_ip_resolver_just_ignore_it_2 {
        proxy_pass https://helloenvoy.herokuapp.com;
    }
    location /this_is_ip_resolver_just_ignore_it_3 {
        proxy_pass http://powr.herokuapp.com;
    }
    location /this_is_ip_resolver_just_ignore_it_4 {
        proxy_pass https://blog.heroku.com;
    }
}
```